# DNS issues only on Ubuntu - but not on my iPad

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I can load any website on my iPad and it's instantaneous. On my new Ubuntu 18.04 laptop it takes 5-10 seconds to initially load any new website. Subsequent loads of the same website are instantaneous on Ubuntu. I can watch full HD YouTube with no issue and my connection is fast.

From Googleing I take it this is some type of DNS issue? But why isn't this issue happening on my iPad? And how do I fix this?

I can't use Ubuntu if all new websites take 5-10 seconds to load. Thanks

Comment: Edit your question to show me the output of `host-v www.ebay.com` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and `systemd-resolve --status` and `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema hope the info I added helps

Comment: See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320  Possible easy fix it to change the /etc/resolv.conf link to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf (from the stub-resolv.conf).  That probably uses the router for the nameserver.

Comment: Edit your question to show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema edited. A temporary solution has been `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf` `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` `sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` with body `nameserver 208.67.222.222`. How do I make a permanent solution? Seems `network connections` is deprecated in *18.04 Bionic Beaver*.

Comment: If that workaround works for you, stick with it for now :-) There's a place in resolved.conf (DNS=) where the IP of the DNS server should go...

Answer (score 0):

I think [this bug is the problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320). And solution #38 is the answer. Thanks to @ubfan1

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
# then added the google nameservers to my file, adding this line.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```